# Replacing special characters in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have this huge DF which encoded in iso8859_15.

I have a few columns which contain names and places in Brazil, so some of them contain special characters such as "í" or "Ô".

I have the key to replace them in a dictionary {'í':'i', 'á':'a', ...}

I tried replacing it a couple of ways (below), but none of them worked.

```
df.replace(dictionary, regex=True, inplace=True) ###BOTH WITH AND WITHOUT REGEX AND REPLACE
```

Also:

```
df.udpate(pd.Series(dic))
```

None of them had the expected output, which would be for strings such as "NÍCOLAS" to become "NICOLAS".

Help?

Comment: How are you pulling the data in initially? CSV?

Comment: Yes. It's a CSV. df=pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\t', low_memory=False, encoding='iso8859_15')

Comment: It must have to do with the encoding, because `df.replace(dictionary, regex=True)` works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The docs on [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) says you have to provide a **nested dictionary**: the *first level is the column name* for which you have to provide a *second dictionary with substitution pairs*.

So, this should work:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'a': ['NÍCOLAS','asdč'], 'b': [3,4]})
>>> df
         a  b
0  NÍCOLAS  3
1     asdč  4

>>> df.replace({'a': {'č': 'c', 'Í': 'I'}}, regex=True)
         a  b
0  NICOLAS  3
1     asdc  4
```

**Edit.** Seems `pandas` also accepts non-nested translation dictionary. In that case, the problem is probably with **character encoding**, *particularly if you use **Python 2***. Assuming your CSV load function decoded the file characters properly (as true Unicode code-points), then you should take care your translation/substitution dictionary is also defined with Unicode characters, like this:

```
dictionary = {u'í': 'i', u'á': 'a'}
```

If you have a definition like this (and using Python 2):

```
dictionary = {'í': 'i', 'á': 'a'}
```

then the actual keys in that dictionary are multibyte strings. Which bytes (characters) they are depends on the actual source file character encoding used, but presuming you use UTF-8, you'll get:

```
dictionary = {'\xc3\xa1': 'a', '\xc3\xad': 'i'}
```

And that would explain why `pandas` fails to replace those chars. So, be sure to use Unicode literals in Python 2: `u'this is unicode string'`.

On the other hand, in Python 3, all strings are Unicode strings, and you don't have to use the `u` prefix (in fact `unicode` type from Python 2 is renamed to `str` in Python 3, and the old `str` from Python 2 is now `bytes` in Python 3).

Comment: hmmm, not necessary - remove nested dict and same results. I think there is some problem with encodings :(

Comment: Hmm, you're right, it seems to work.. But don't they say in the docs it has to be a nested dict?

Comment: nested lists are used if need replace only column `a` and column `b` with strings cannot be replaced. So instead subset like `df[['a']] = df[['a']].replace(...)` is possible used nested dict.

Comment: Yeah. Tried using a nested in the whole df, and the output was the same. Then I tried doing the same to a specific column. No good either.

Comment: @RaphaelHernandes Which Python (version) are you using?

Comment: It's Python 2.7.13

Comment: @RaphaelHernandes, can you try it on Python3? It handles unicode properly.

Comment: That's it! Just did it in Python3. `df.replace(dictionary, regex=True, inplace=True)`. Without inplace it wouldn't work

Comment: @RaphaelHernandes, inplace had nothing to do with your problem (it just replaces on current df, not creating a new one). The problem obviously was with the way you loaded your CSV, or the way you represented translation map (you should have used `u'é'`, etc.)

Comment: I see. And yes, the original file was really messy (I've had lots of problems using it, but I wasn't the one who created it, though). What do you mean by `u'é'`?

Comment: @RaphaelHernandes, the explanation was too long for the comment, so I updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 9):

`replace` works out of the box without specifying a specific column in Python 3.

Load Data:

```
df=pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', low_memory=False, encoding='iso8859_15')
df
```

Result:

```
col1    col2
0   he  hello
1   Nícolas shárk
2   welcome yes
```

Create Dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'í':'i', 'á':'a'}
```

Replace:

```
df.replace(dictionary, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
 col1   col2
0   he  hello
1   Nicolas shark
2   welcome yes
```

Comment: I tried it both ways (with and without regex=True, with and without inplace=True). None of them worked :(

Comment: was the output the same as the input? or was it different than the input, just not what you expected?

Comment: @CameronTaylor - do you test it in python2? [because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596529/replacing-special-characters-in-pandas-dataframe#comment78153592_45596654)

Comment: Yes! It was. But it worked in Python3 :) had to use inplace, though

Comment: glad it worked! yes, in my example I was just printing it out, so i did not include `inplace`. I'll add it for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

If someone get the following error message

> multiple repeat at position 2

try this `df.replace(dictionary, regex=False, inplace=True)`

instead of 
`df.replace(dictionary, regex=True, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

replace  `|`   with `,`    in `my_specific_column` dataframe column

```
df.my_specific_column = df.my_specific_column.str.replace('|', ',')
```