# How to replace Swedish characters ä, å, ö in columns names in python?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, python-unicode

I have a dataframe with some columns names having Swedish characters (ö,ä,å). I would like to replace these characters with simple o,a,a instead.

I tried to convert the columns names to str and replace the characters, it works but then it gets complicated if I want to assign back the str as columns names, i.e., there are multiple operations needed which makes it complicated.

I tried the following code which replaces the Swedish characters in columns names with the English alphabets and returns the result as str.

```
from unidecode import unidecode
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',str(df.columns).decode('utf-8')).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Is there a way to use the returning str as columns names for the dataframe? If not, then is there a better way to replace the Swedish characters in columns names?

Comment: SO answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596529/replacing-special-characters-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @run-out I know how to replace cells values/characters but was not sure about how to change characters in columns names. The solution provided by jezrael works for me.

Comment: Hanif cool, sorry about that, and @jezrael is the best....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me working first normalize, then encode to ascii and last decode to `utf-8`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['aä','åa','oö'])

df.columns = (df.columns.str.normalize('NFKD')
                        .str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
                        .to_series()
                        .str.decode('utf-8'))
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [aa, aa, oo]
Index: []
```

Another solutions with `map` or list comprehension:

```
import unicodedata

f = lambda x: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
df.columns = df.columns.map(f)
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [aa, aa, oo]
Index: []
```

---

```
import unicodedata

df.columns = [unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8') 
                     for x in df.columns]
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [aa, aa, oo]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be lot of manual work when you have lots of columns, but one way to do this is to use `str.replace` like this:

```
    bänk  röund
0   1     3
1   2     4
2   3     5

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('ä', 'a')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('ö', 'o')


    bank  round
0   1     3
1   2     4
2   3     5
```

Comment: yes, your solution works but as you mentioned, it will be some manual work specially when I am working with 30-35 dataframes and each df has more than 100 columns.

Comment: I agree @Hanif, I upvoted jezrael's answer as well, since its way better.